# How to Save Uploaded file in server machine temporarily

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

I am using a portal for uploading a data file in CSV format.when i am trying to upload a file,it is temporarily saved in C:\temp,and then it is bulk inserted into the DB server.

Issue:Data file is saving in the local system...not in the DB server temp.Because of this i am getting an error like C:\temp not found.

Mycode:

```
       filePath = Path.Combine("C:\\temp", fileName);
```

Can anyone please help me to save my data in server temp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the server is in the same network you can use **UNC** pattern:

```
\\RemoteServer\SharedFolder\YourFiles
```

I had a similar case where I build the path myself:

```
var MachineName ="SomeServer";
var location = "Temp";
var fileName = "SomeFile.txt";

var path = string.Format(@"\\{0}\C$\{1}", MachineName, location);
var target = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(path, fileName));
```

Now you can use `File.Copy`